# Storing commands in files

Tags: tcsh

I'm trying to store commands in a file, so I can just easily call the file usnig the below bit of code;

```
./test
```

I need to run this bit of code;

```
Set n=0 ; foreach sql ( *_*.sql)
foreach? sed “s/_/-/g” $sql
foreach? @ n ++
foreach? End
echo You changed $n files
```

I type the following;

```
set n = 0 > test
foreach sql ( *_*.sql) >> test
```

When I get to this point, I ave a blank line appear within the terminal so I type the following 3 lines blind;

```
foreach? sed “s/_/-/g” $sql
foreach? @ n ++
foreach? End
```

I then finish with:

```
echo 'echo You changed $n files' >> test
```

Once I finish the output file only contains this:

```
foreach? sed "s/_/-/g" $sql
foreach? @ n ++
foreach? end
echo You changed $n file
```

Totally missing out the set commands and the beginning of the foreach loop. What am I missing here? or is it just not possible?

EDITTED

```
#!/bin/tcsh
set n=0
foreach sql ( *_*.sql )
sed "s/_/-/g" $sql
@ n ++
end
echo You changed $n files
chmod 777 test
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using a text editor?

Comment: I initially tried that but weren't sure if it was best to do it this way. I've put the error i've been receiving while doing it within the answer comments below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have multiple problems in your script.

First off, a text editor is *the* right way to create a script 99% of the time.  Building it manually line by line with echo commands is tedious and offers no advantage at all.  (The other 1% covers cases where you're on a system that doesn't have an editor you're familiar with, or where there's a good reason to use a program to generate a script automatically, neither of which should apply in your case.)

The first line should be `#!/bin/tcsh -f`, not `#!/bin/tcsh`.  The `-f` tells it not to source your startup files (`.tcshrc`, `.cshrc`, `.login`), so your script will be self-contained.  The lack of `-f` probably won't cause any problems, but having it is good practice.  (Note: this does not apply to `sh` or `bash` scripts; for those shells, `-f` means something else entirely.)

This line:

```
sed "s/_/-/g" $sql
```

reads each file, changing all underscores to hyphens -- but the output is written to stdout, *not* back to the input file.  The files themselves are not changed.  Since you later do this:

```
echo You changed $n files
```

I presume that doesn't fit in with your plans.

Modifying files in place is actually moderately tricky.  I'd do something like this:

```
sed "s/_/-/g" $sql > $sql.tmp && mv $sql.tmp $sql
```

This modifies the file `$sql`, writing the modified version to a temporary file.  *If* that succeeds, it then renames the temporary file to `$sql`.

There's also a `-i` option to `sed` that will do something similar; another approach is:

```
sed -i.bak "s/_/-/g" $sql
```

Indentation is your friend.  Everything between the `foreach` and `end` lines should be indented to show the structure of your code.  (I use 4 spaces myself; some people prefer a different number of spaces, or use tabs.)

Finally, the `chmod 777 test` should not be in the `test` script itself.  You need to execute that command from the command line, to make the `test` script executable.  And `777` is a bad idea; it makes your script readable, executable, *and writable* by everyone on the system.  Use `chmod +x test` instead.

Be sure you execute the script by typing `./test`, not just `test`.  (Your question says you're already doing that.)  Otherwise, you might execute the built-in `test` command rather than your script.  There's nothing wrong with naming your script `test`, as long as you (a) consistently use the `./test` syntax to invoke it, and (b) you don't have the `.` directory in your `$PATH`.

If you're going to be writing a lot of scripts, you should consider using `sh` or `bash` rather than `csh` or `tcsh`.  [This essay](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) explains why.

Finally (and this might be the most important lesson here), you haven't actually told us what you're trying to do.  I *think* you want to modify the contents of certain files, replacing underscores with hyphens.  Or do you want to change their names rather than their contents?  It's impossible to be sure what you're trying to do, because all you've shown us is a chunk of code *that doesn't work*.  There's nothing wrong with showing us non-working code, but we can't advise you how to fix it unless you tell us, in English, what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hey Keith, I appreciate the detailed post but it just doesn't want to work. I'm now getting a message saying 'unknown option: `- Usage:tcsh [ -bcdefilmnnqstvVxX ] [ argument ... ]. I've been set a task where I need to change all types of a certain file that have an underscore character within them and record how many files I've actually changed. It's basically that simple, I just can't find any resources to help me figure out how it should actually be done.

Comment: Ignore that it might of been what you originally said about the 'test' file name, I changed it to another random name and it worked fine. thanks for you help here!

Comment: @r0bb077: I'm glad you got it working, but if you were invoking the script as `./test`, the name of the script should not have made any difference.  It must have been some other change that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Trying what you're doing from the shell command line is fraught with problems.  You have to `echo` and redirect *every* line and you have to quote any shell metacharacters lest they be interpreted by the current shell and not make it into the file you're creating.  You are better off using a text editor to edit your `test` file and entering the shell commands directly there.

Comment: I had been trying this but I can't get the terminal to recognise the foreach loop. I have this within the file - 'foreach sql (*_*.sql)' but I keep getting error systax error at lie 2: `(' unexpected. Any ideas

Comment: You're writing a `tcsh`-style script.  Could it be that you're inadvertently trying to execute it with a Bourne type shell, e.g. `bash` or `sh`?  That would explain the error message.  Put `#!/bin/tcsh` at the top of the file to tell the system to use `tcsh` as the interpreter.

Comment: Hey Kyle, I appreciated your help here, but I'm getting error 'command not found' now i've inserted that. I've edited my original post above to show you what i've got in my file now. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to use `end` instead of `End`.

Comment: Sorry Kyle, still getting the same thing?!

Comment: Comment out lines one at a time until the error message goes away.  That's your problem line.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, use an editor to write shell scripts.

Here the corrections to your *edited version*:

You need to write `set n=0` instead of `n=0` to get rid of the "command not found" error message,

`foreach sql ( *_*.sql )` instead of `foreach sql  *_*.sql`

and `end` instead of `End`.

You need normal quotes `"` instead of `“` to quote the parameters for sed.

Comment: Hi Jofel, thanks for your input but I still seem to be getting exactly the same error message after your changes. I've edited my post again with what I have

Comment: @r0bb077 see the answer from Keith Thompson